# set the different number from 1 to N

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph-algorithm

I have a number of nodes A, I want to change the number in order from 1 to 4. And change the link as link_new in the following code. Could you help me with that?

```
A= [23;
    24; 
    27; 
    45];
link= [23 24;
       24 27 ;
       24 45;
       27 45];
```

result

```
A_new = [1;
         2;
         3;
         4]
link_new =[1 2;
           2 3;
           2 4;
           3 4]
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything? How have your efforts fallen short of your desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = [23; 24; 27; 45];
link = [23, 24; 24, 27; 24, 45; 27, 45];

A_new = A;
link_new = link;
for idx = 1:numel(A)
  a = A(idx);
  A_new(idx) = idx;
  link_new(link_new == a) = idx;
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work if `A` contains any elements smaller than `numel(A)`. For example `A=[23,1]`, it first replaces 23 with 1, now there are two nodes called 1, and all their links have been confused.

Comment: I assume A is sorted. Should have mentioned that, thanks!